# TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to parse a string which has a military time hour value

```
'10:00:00'
```

I am able to do this with

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('10:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
datetime.time(10, 0)
```

Then I get the current time in a specific time zone:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()+ datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 11, 26, 1, 909000)
```

What I'm trying to do is compare the time from the string with the current time in utc. But when I compare the values

```
>>> bne_time_now > tag_time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.time
```

What I think I need to do is set a default time value when I parse the string but I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `datetime.datetime` object to a `datetime.time` object using the [time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) method.

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=10)).time()
datetime.time(11, 33, 51, 523382)
```

Then you can compare the two time objects.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I still need to read string of time though, not sure how I do it with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this working:

```
>>> today = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> today
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 1, 52, 33, 253000)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('10:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').replace(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day)
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 10, 0)
```

just posting here in case someone else needs this solution